# How do I enable all warnings in Visual Studio 2008 in a project?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I want to print all the warnings in my project built in VS2008. As has been suggested at other questions, the project properties only gives me up to `/W4` level warnings when I want to enable `/Wall`. Below is a snapshot of properties. Is there a way to enable `/Wall` in VS2008 for a project?

[image]

Comment: Is this a C++ project?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are working with C++? In this case, you can add this flag in the "Command Line" options directly:

[image]

Notice that the output can be *too* verbose to be usable.