# How to enable *all* compiler warnings for major compilers

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++, clang++

I think we all know how compiler warnings can help prevent bugs and that [it's good to have them enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings).

So the question is: how to enable *all* compiler warnings?

The major C++ compilers for me are:

- g++
- clang++
- Visual Studio's compiler

I am aware of the common settings for these compilers:

- `-Wall` `-Wextra` `-pedantic` (common for g++ and clang++)
- `/W4` (vc++)

However, there are some more warnings that can be enabled more individually (like for example `-Wconversion`).

Is is possible to enable *all* warnings without passing a huge number of individual switches? If *all* is impractical (due to for example lots of warnings generated by standard library headers, or many false positives), how to enable the most useful subset?

I understand "the most useful subset" differs depending on the project, but perhaps there is a good subset each project can start with.

Comment: You don't want all warnings. The reason it's not automatically all on is because there's false positives, and how much you tolerate them is a decision.

Comment: `clang++` `-Weverything` and then `-` the ones you do not want, like all `c++98-*` compatibility warnings.

Comment: @PasserBy: and how can I make my decision if I don't enable all and see how bad the situation is? And yes, I'm fully aware of the false positives and the possible noise.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714827/how-to-turn-on-literally-all-of-gccs-warnings; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24075528/how-do-i-enable-all-warnings-in-visual-studio-2008-in-a-project/24284555

Comment: I would suggest that any answer to *this* question would actually be better suited as a supplemental answer to the *linked* question. But I'd like to see others' opinions before/if I close this as a duplicate.

Comment: ... plus there are the Q/As that @user17732522 just linked.